# Apache solr collection

Tags: xml, collections, solr, admin

I am new to Apache Solr so bear with me. I am trying to create a collection/core that remains on my admin page every time I load Solr 4.10.4 on my Mac. Currently, I have to make a new core every time I open up the Solr Admin page.

Currently, I have my solrconfig.xml, schema.xml and solr.xml file and they look as follows:

Solrconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
<luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_43</luceneMatchVersion>
<requestDispatcher handleSelect="false">
<httpCaching never304="true" />
</requestDispatcher>
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler" />
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />
<requestHandler name="/admin" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
<requestHandler name="/analysis/field" class="solr.
FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" startup="lazy" />
</config>
```

Schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema version="1.5">
<fields>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"
required="true"/>
<field name="addr_from" type="string" indexed="true"
stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="addr_to" type="string" indexed="true"
stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="subject" type="string" indexed="true"
stored="true" required="true"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<types>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />
</types>
</schema>
```

Solr.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<collection2>
<schema version="1.5">
<fields>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"
required="true"/>
<field name="addr_from" type="string" indexed="true"
stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="addr_to" type="string" indexed="true"
stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="subject" type="string" indexed="true"
stored="true" required="true"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<types>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />
</types>
</schema>


<solr persistent="true">
```

Comment: This is not normal behaviour in any way - do you get any errors in the Solr log when the collection is created? The schema doesn't go into `solr.xml`, so you might have an issue with Solr even starting?

Comment: What version of Solr are you using?

Comment: My solr seems to start fine, but even when I put the schema in I still don't get a permanent collection.  And @AlexandreRafalovitch I am using Solr 4.10.4

Comment: How exactly are you creating your core/collection? Where are you creating it?

Comment: I'm using Web Wrangler to create the files and then I'm using Xquery to run the code. @TMBT

Comment: Have you tried creating your core and config files at the terminal? It's a bit tedious, but I would be curious to see if you still lost your collection from /your/path/to/solr/server/solr/collectionName if you created them at the terminal using something like nano or vi(m).

Comment: Also, your solr.xml is going to cause you problems if you put the schema in it. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Format+of+solr.xml

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! The problem was within the version 4.10.4, once I updated it and used Solr version 6.1.0 and used the Solr Tutorial the problem was fixed. Thanks for the help!